# Sort JSON in numerical order in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

This is the JSON returned:

```
"unit": [
        {
            "unit_id": "268",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "13",
            "unit_name": "File Handling and Dictionaries",
            "unit_no": "6",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "274",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "24",
            "unit_name": "Object Oriented Programming",
            "unit_no": "5",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "300",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "14",
            "unit_name": "Decision Control Statements",
            "unit_no": "2",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "304",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "29",
            "unit_name": "Problem Solving, Programming and Python Programming",
            "unit_no": "1",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "392",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "11",
            "unit_name": "Functions & Modules",
            "unit_no": "3",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "393",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "28",
            "unit_name": "Strings",
            "unit_no": "4",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "298",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "59",
            "no_chapters": "16",
            "unit_name": "Electromagnetism",
            "unit_no": "1",
        },
```

I want to sort the JSON with respect to **univ_spec_sub_id** and **unit_no.** . For example all the **unit_no.** sorted in numerical order **under univ_spec_sub_id** as 53. I can't figure how to implement it.

This is the code written for the post request and to print out the JSON returned.

```
Future<Semdata> semdata(String url, {Map body} ) {
    return http.post(url,
          body:body).then((http.Response response){
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }
    var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
    
    List unitdata = extractdata["unit"];
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(response.body);
    

    for(Map<String, dynamic> unitMap in decodedData['unit']){
      db.saveunit(unitMap);
    }
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    return Semdata.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it easier if you convert JSON to Object and do any sort algorithm later.

this website will auto convert JSON to dart Object for you https://app.quicktype.io/

after you get your Object you put them into an List Array and call this function

```
List arrayOfUnit = [object1,object2,object3,object4];
bubbleSort(arrayOfUnit); //call this funtion to sort
print(arrayOfUnit[0],arrayOfUnit[1],arrayOfUnit[2]) // to check is it sort correctly
```

**bubbleSort code:**

```
void bubbleSort(List list) {
  //list is an array of your Object
  //example > List unitList = [unit1,unit2,unit3];
if (list == null || list.length == 0) return;

 int n = list.length;
 int i, step;
 for (step = 0; step < n; step++) {
   for ( i = 0; i < n - step - 1; i++) {
     if (list[i].sub_id > list[i + 1].sub_id) {
       if(list[i].unit_no > list[i + 1].unit_no){
         swap(list, i);
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
void swap(List list, int i) {
 int temp = list[i];
 list[i] = list[i+1];
 list[i+1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Still.. How can i sort the object w.r.t 2 attributes?

Comment: Well.. Is there any built in function you know about?